# Can't connect to backend after quasar build

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a project made with quasar, I have a proxy that maps the calls on the app to my backend API, but when it builds using `quasar build` it generates the `dist` folder, for testing I use a server if it works but the calls that the app makes don't work
[image]

This is supposed to make a call to `http://localhost:8080/getCategories`

Here is the proxy conf:

```
proxyTable: {
  '/api': {
    target: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/api': ''
    }
  }
}
```

When I try it with dev server, dev server running on `8081`
[image]

I do not know if I have to change the API calls, all the calls I do are like `this.$http.get('/api/getCategories')` for a sample.

Not sure if I explained things clearly, hope someone can help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I've fixed that, don't know if this is the correct way, will try to explain for other people that may have had the same problem.

First of all i've removed the proxyTable from the `config/index.js`, then added one environment, one in the `config/dev.env.js` that looks like this:

```
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  API: "'http://localhost:8080'"
})
```

and one for the `config/prov.env.js` that looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  API: "'http://my-website.com:8080'"
}
```

Then all the AJAX calls that I've used with VueResource look like this:

```
this.$http.get(`${process.env.API}/path/`)
    .then(response => response.json(), console.log)
            .then(response => {
                 console.log(response)
            })
```

Totally worked for me, hope someone's find this useful!

Comment: does this also work with Post? I'm having the same problem with POST and yes it says the same error.